# Declarative macros

Tags: rust, macros, metaprogramming

I'm trying to learn about macros, as meta programming is a concept I really loved when I found about it, and it can be really usefull in my current project.

I'm trying to make a macro to create entities with any number of components, something like :

```
let ecs = ECS::new();
let entity1 = create_entity!(ecs);
let entity2 = create_entity!(ecs, Position{x:1, y:2});
let entity3 = create_entity!(ecs, Position{x:3, y:-1}, Velocity{vx:0, vy:1});
```

There are several things I don't know how to do here :

- How can I have this fixed first parameter, and ensure it is a struct of type ECS ? the same way `println!()` will allways have a string first ? I've looked the definition of `println!()`, but couldn't look deeper into the functions that are called.
- How can I pass a whole struct as a parameter, and interpret this correctly ?

As an example, here is a working function to create an entity with one component :

```
fn create_entity_1<C1, C2>(ecs: ECS, component1: C1, component2: C2) -> Entity {
    let result_entity = ecs.create_entity();
    ecs.components.add_comp_to_last(&result_entity, component1);
    ecs.components.add_comp_to_last(&result_entity, component2);
    return result_entity;
}
```

And obviously, with more component I "simply" need to add more of the second line.

This is what i've tried so far, but I'm struggling to understand what I'm doing :

```
// macros to create entities with any number of components
macro_rules! create_entity {
    ($ecs:expr; $($comp:literal),*) => {
        let result_entity = $ecs.create_entity();
        $ecs.components.add_comp_to_last(&result_entity, comp);
    }
}
```

I've tried to read both [The book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-06-macros.html) and [The little book of macros](https://veykril.github.io/tlborm/), But I'm lacking concrete example or explanations of the whole thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You look like you were on the right track so let me fill in the rest:

```
macro_rules! create_entity {
    ($ecs:expr) => { ECS::create_entity(&$ecs) };
    ($ecs:expr; $($comp:expr),*) => { {
        let result_entity = ECS::create_entity(&$ecs);
        $(
            $ecs.components.add_comp_to_last(&result_entity, $comp);
        )*
        result_entity
    } };
}
```

- Separate `$ecs:expr` and `$ecs:expr; $($comp:expr),*` into separate rules, the former of which simply creates the entity without components.
- Change `$comp` from `literal` to `expr`. Only things like `"strings"`, `42`, or `true` are literals and you likely want to be able to accept any expression that creates a component anyway.
- Use a block and return the created entity: `{ ...; result_entity }` (note the extra braces above `{ { ... } }`). That way you can assign the result of the macro to a variable as you desired, otherwise `let entity = create_entity!(ecs, ...);` wouldn't work since the macro would yield multiple statements instead of a single block of statements.
- Use macro repetition rules to expand `$comp` to multiple expressions using `$(...)*` within the macro output.
- Use the fully qualified syntax to call `ECS::create_entity()` directly if you want to ensure that the `$ecs` is an `ECS` (or reference to one) and not simply accept variables that could act like an `ECS`. The `println!` macro works differently since a macro can distinguish between kinds of literals (first parameter can't just be an expression of type `&str` it *must* be a literal), but here you can't distinguish in a macro between a variable of type `ECS` and a variable of some other type. You simply have to construct the generated code to produce an error if it wasn't the expected type.

See it working on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3359418092d370f4d22d8e0807c8a32c).

<sup>You use a comma separator after `ecs` in your example usage but you use a semicolon when defining the macro rule (meaning `create_entity!(ecs; ...)`), I kept with the semicolon here but its trivial to change.</sup>

Comment: When you say it's trivial to replace the semi colon with a comma, do you simply have to swicth it in the second match arm parameter of the macro ? I thought the comma was reserved (like in the ```$($comp:expr),*``` pattern) and the semi colon would act like a comma in functions.
Anyway, this worked nicely ! I'm still going to try some things, to keep learning macros.

Comment: @LucioleMaléfique give it a shot! [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cd58e9cd34d393f1ce46c27bb2bd5e5b). Yes you can simply switch it in the second rule. Commas are not reserved just for repetitions.